# Unable to run app on my iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging

I am running my app with today widget to iPhone 6 and sometimes I can't beacuse I have this message.

> This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle
>   identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains.
>   Bundle identifiers must be unique.

I don't know why beacuse I deleted that app from my iPhone. I tried to change provisioning profile in widget and app and I have same result. 
Restart iphone and mac doesn't work either.

I have those IDs and Groups:

- Group ID: group.drozd.com
- App Bundle ID: drozd.com.app
- Widget Bundle ID: drozd.com.app.widget

Can someone help me with this?

**Update 1**

I fixed that by updating a provisioning profile

Comment: have you used this bundle identifier for some other application also?

Comment: No I haven't. I tested this on the iPhone 5 with older version of that app then on iPhone 6+ but he it empty. And I have same result. I removed all provisioning profiles from phone and still I can't run it.